# How to display grid of data in crystal reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am having issues with Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2008.

I am tasked with creating a report that displays data in a grid, from testing scores..

I would like the data to be displayed like the following

```
Results for Exam <Exam Title>

               <Question Name 1><Question Name 2><Question Name 3><...>
<Candidate 1>    <Score>          <Score>          <Score>
<Candidate 2>    <Score>          <Score>          <Score>
<Candidate 3>    <Score>          <Score>          <Score>
...
```

The question names and number of questions can change for the exam.

Things I have tried:

- Formatting with multiple columns in
  the selection expert.
- Grouping
- Cross Tab (almost there, but I don't need
  the totals)

As I am using in memory objects to calculate the scores for the candidates, dataset/object structure is not an issue, I can basically give crystal reports in a format that would best suite this issue.

I find it really difficult to believe that crystal reports cannot do this, I am basically looking for the crystal reports equivalent of the html table tags.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with Cross-Tabs. To get rid of the totals, enter the Cross-Tab Expert, select the Customize Style tab and check the Suppress Row Grand Totals and Suppress Column Grand Totals options.